# Growing in a bottle

Tags: flowering

I have this soda bottle and I wanted to know - is there was any way to grow some type of orange flower in it?

[image: The bottle]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can grow plants in anything! The only issue I see is that the bottle has no drainage. Drill some holes at the bottom and put rocks in the bottom before putting the soil inside.

I guess it also depends on the specific flower you want to put inside of it and the space it needs to spread out. A very small flower will do, but anything close to a tulip is way too big for the bottle. To give the plant more space to grow out, cut the skinny top of the bottle off and smoothen it (so you don't cut yourself), then leave some space at the top from the exit of the bottle to the soil so dirt has space to expand with the root system.